# Export text file in a loop to know the progress

Tags: r, loops

I am doing computation with a very big database and when I start a loop in general, it can take few hours. 
I need to create a text file in the loop, to know at which `[i]` I am.

The file can be overwritten at evry `[i]`. It is just to control how it is going without stopping the program.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`writeLines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/writeLines) function. The second argument allows you to specify a file path:

```
writeLines(as.character(i), 'progress.log')
```

Comment: Good catch, the argument needs to be a character string. R *usually* performs this conversion implicitly but not here.